# use of undeclared identifier 'data' C++

Tags: c++

> "Write a function, named sums(), that has two input parameters; an array of floats; and an integer,
>   n, which is the number of values stored in the array. Compute the sum of the positive values in the array
>   and the sum of the negative values. Also count the number of values in each category. Return these four
>   answers through output reference parameters.
>
> Write a main program that reads no more than 10 real numbers and stores them in an array. Stop reading numbers when a 0 is entered. Call the sums() function and print the answers it returns. Also compute and print the average values of the positive and negative sets."

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sums(float data[], int count, float& posSum, int& posCnt, float& negSum, int& negCnt);
double input(double UserInput);

int main()
{
    float data[10];
    int count = 10 ;
    double UserInput = 0;
    float posSum=0.0, negSum=0.0; //sum of positives and negatives
    int posCnt =0, negCnt=0; // count of postive and negatives

    input(UserInput);
    sums(data, count, posSum,posCnt, negSum, negCnt);

    cout << "Positive sum: " << posSum << endl;
    cout << "Positive count:" << posCnt << endl;
    cout << "Negative sum: " << negSum << endl;
    cout << "Negative count:" << negCnt << endl;
    return 0;
}

double input(double UserInput) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << "Enter a real number or '0' to stop: " ;
        cin >> UserInput;
        if(UserInput == 0)break;

        data[i] = UserInput;
    }
    return UserInput;
}

void sums(float data[], int count, float& posSum, int& posCnt, float& negSum, int& negCnt){

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(data[i] > 0){
            posCnt += 1;
            posSum += data[i];
        }
        else{
            negCnt += 1;
            negSum += data[i];
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me an error when trying to compile it saying "use of undeclared identifier 'data'" on line 32 in the input function.

Comment: That's because `data` is not declared within the scope of `input` - you probably intended to pass it in as a parameter `float* data`, similarly to how you did for `sums`?

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Prefer using standard C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and spend several days or weeks reading more about C++. [Use the debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Stack Overflow is not a *do-my-homework* service.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the data is not declared in the function `input`, you should use a `float` pointer.

```
void input(float *data)
{
   float UserInput;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
   {
      cout << "Enter a real number or '0' to stop: ";
      cin >> UserInput;
      if (UserInput == 0)break;

      data[i] = UserInput;
  }
  return;
}

int main()
{
   float *data;

   data = (float*)malloc(10 * sizeof(float));
   input(data);

   cout << data[0];

   free(data);
   system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

This should be an accurate example. Good Luck with your following homework.